# Do you have a modeling notation that you use for MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, modeling, notation

Hopefully (but not necessarily) one that is independent of language or framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a simple model at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

you can find a uml diagram of the model and view here: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx. the controller is sometimes in the gui.

there are some flavours of mvc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter

Comment: +1 for your first reference has these lists:

Implementations of MVC as GUI frameworks  

Implementations of MVC as web-based frameworks

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple one of my own devising:

- a square for Model (M is a square letter) - squares also look like tables
- a circle for Controller (C is a round letter) - circles indicate the controllers are for the "flow", they glue model and view together
- a triangle for View, point on the bottom (V is a triangular letter)

This is for when I am doing a Visio type diagram. This simple mnemonic keeps it easy to remember.